# How do I ignore routing for few files type asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

suppose i want that routing should ignore *.js files *.css and *.png etc

i search google and found solution. which i implement in my page but still js files are not downloading.

here is my code

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("images/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("Styles/{*pathInfo}");


        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source", "UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source/{ID}/{Title}", "~/UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source.aspx");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source2", "UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source/{Question}/{ID}/{Title}/{Page}", "~/UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source.aspx");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source1", "Feedback/{ID}/{Title}", "~/Feedback.aspx");
        //RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source1", "Source.aspx{?}{ID}{&}{Title}", "~/UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source.aspx");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("product", "Data/product.aspx/{*ID}", "~/UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source.aspx");  // url mapping with * routing

    }
```

so tell me my code is ok for Ignore few files type. why my js is not downloading.
my css file are in Styles folder, my js files are in Script folder etc. the Script & Styles folder in root. please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per Phil Haack, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljs}", new {alljs=@".*\.js(/.*)?"});
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allpng}", new {allpng=@".*\.png(/.*)?"});
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allcss}", new {allcss=@".*\.css(/.*)?"});
```

Comment: i use routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljs}", new {alljs=@".*\.js(/.*)?"});
still i am getting the same error. what it means. =@".*\.js(/.*)?". do i need to provide my js file path?

Comment: No that shouldn't be necessary. Try replacing `routes` with `RouteTable.Routes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");
Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.png");
```

Comment: do i need to write with full path like Routes.IgnoreRoute("{scripts/myjs}.js");

Comment: No, just copy and paste my code. I used it for .txt files and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ResolveUrl**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/path to script ")%>'></script>
```